# E/com.parse.PushService

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hey every body i have a probleme with PushService i had this message

ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.merrou.GuideApp-1/lib/x86
05-03 22:53:02.879 28956-28956/com.merrou.GuideApp E/com.parse.PushService: The Parse push service cannot start because Parse.initialize has not yet been called. If you call Parse.initialize from an Activity's onCreate, that call should instead be in the Application.onCreate. Be sure your Application class is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml with the android:name property of your  tag.

first i search in google and I found it necessary to initialize your name class in application in AndroidManifest but when i initialized i got an com.merrou.GuideApp.MAinActivity is not assignable to com.merrou.GuideApp.Application

Thank you for your help

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.merrou.GuideApp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.merrou.GuideApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.merrou.GuideApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        >


        <activity
            android:name="com.merrou.GuideApp.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.merrou.GuideApp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragment_TourList"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragment_DetailTour"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.merrou.GuideApp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        //Parse push notification
        Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_application_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
        // populate the navigation drawer
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUserData(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), getResources().getString(R.string.email), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo_app));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position) {
            case 0: //stats
                fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Fragment_Guide.TAG);
                if (fragment == null) {
                    fragment = new Fragment_Guide();
                }
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, Fragment_Guide.TAG).commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Fragment_Favorite.TAG);
                if (fragment == null) {
                    fragment = new Fragment_Favorite();
                }
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, Fragment_Favorite.TAG).commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Fragment_About.TAG);
                if (fragment == null) {
                    fragment = new Fragment_About();
                }
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, Fragment_About.TAG).commit();
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.unused, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Parse's services is downing. Change to GCM

Comment: I don't know what you want to mean can you  explaining to me and thank you